# Is there a way to make an autoincrement field that depends a foreign key in laravel migrations

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration

I'm using postgres 12 as DB.

I have an invoice table, with user_id FK, and a date.

I would like to have a autoincrement field that depends on the FK and the date. For instance

```
year: 2019,user_id: 2,incremental: 1
year: 2019,user_id: 2,incremental: 2
year: 2020,user_id: 2,incremental: 1 // Because year changes, incremental start to 1 again
year: 2020,user_id: 2,incremental: 2
year: 2020,user_id: 2,incremental: 3 
year: 2020,user_id: 3,incremental: 1 // Because user_id changes, incremental start to 1 again
year: 2020,user_id: 3,incremental: 2
year: 2020,user_id: 3,incremental: 3
year: 2020,user_id: 4,incremental: 4
```

Is there a way to achieve that directly with migrations, or should I code the logic in the code ?

Comment: This is much easier done using code tbh. The only I can think of that can be done on the DB level is using stored procedures.

Comment: Since you mention using a migration, is this a one-time thing (in which case the UPDATE query would be simple enough) or do you want this behaviour for future rows too (which would make more sense since you also mention an autoincrement field)? If it's the latter, you could use a trigger instead.

Comment: yep, each time I will generate an invoice, I want the filename to be: year-user-autoIncrementedNumber, so whenever an invoice is created